# Switch off V_BACKUP

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, batteries, lithium-ion

Please see the below schematic.

[image]

V_BCKP is used to supply back-up power to the secondary MCU. V_BCKP allowed range is 1.7 to 3.5 V. The current consumption at V_BCKP pin is only a few μA. The LDO's dropout is ~250 mV. The 3.7 V cell voltage is expected to vary between 2.8 and 4.2 V.

I also need to add an option to switch off V_BCKP by MAIN MCU in case the secondary MCU is in an abnormal state.
Main MCU can switch off V_BCKP by pulling high pin 1. Please let me know your comments and any issue you see.

Comment: To add, LDO has internal PULLDOWN on EN Pin. EN pin will not remain in flating state. If nothing is connected to EN then LDO will be off as per its datasheet.  Another thing, all are enhancement type mosfet.

Comment: When PIn1 is low, the Q3 should be ON.

Comment: I can't quite see how Q3 ever gets turned on.  If Pin1 is high (so Q5 and Q4 are on) then Q3's gate is at a slightly lower voltage than its source, which means Q3 is off.  If Pin1 is low (Q5 and Q4 off) then Q3's gate is at ground, and Q3 is again off.

Comment: Q3 is PNP. so when Q5 and Q4 are off then Q3's gate will be grounded. Q3 Source always at cell voltage. Isn't Q3 should be ON. ?

Comment: Yes, I misread the schematic.  If Q3 is a PFET then the LDO EN pin should be high when PIN1 is low, and low otherwise (depending somewhat on the exact characteristics of the FETs).  Is there a reason that Pin 1 can't drive EN directly?  (Will the LDO have problems with EN being a higher voltage than IN, for example?).

Comment: There is a switch after 3.7V cell which will disconnect power to MAIN and secondary mcu. This V_Bckup is required permanently to Secondary MCU for quick HOT start. Secondary MCU has two pins VDD and V_Backup

Comment: I'm wondering if there could simply be a PFET with source connected to the 3.7V cell, gate to PIN1, and drain (via resistor or directly) to LDO EN.  If PIN1 is low then the PFET is on and EN is pulled up to almost the source voltage.  If PIN1 is high then the PFET is off (as long as high is more than the highest possible battery voltage of 4.2V less the threshold voltage) and the internal pulldown in the LDO pulls EN low.  Note that with this suggestion (if it works) or your original circuit, the default is EN low.  For instance, if the main CPU isn't working, EN is low.

Comment: What's the regulator's output voltage? Does it guarantee *any* output at all when its input (cell voltage) drops below \$V_{OUT}+250mV\$?

Comment: Regulator output voltage is 3.3V.  But V_bckup range allowed is 1.8V to 3.6V. cell voltage will never drop below 2.5V due to BMS. So if cell voltage is 2.5V, then output should be 2.5 - .250  = 2.25V .  Correct ?